# false if statements being called/variable not being assigned?

Tags: python, if-statement

I wasn't too sure what to call this post.

Anyways, what I'm trying to do is assign 'diff' to a user input, and if 'diff' is not average or advanced, recall the function so that the user can (hopefully) enter average or advanced.

However, no matter what I input, it will always recall the function, even if the input is 'average' or 'advanced'.

Code -

```
def choices():
    global diff
    diff = input("Choose a difficulty: Average/Advanced ")
    diff = diff.lower()
    x = 0
    while x > 1:
        if diff == 'average':
            print('Difficulty set to average.')
            x = x + 1
        elif diff == 'advanced':
            print('Difficulty set to advanced.')
            x = x + 1

    if diff != 'average' or 'advanced':
        print('Your input is invalid. Please try again.')
        choices()

choices()
```

The same thing is also happening for another decision I have that is similar to this, but I figured that there's no point in putting it down if it follows the same logic.

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm only a beginner.

Comment: That's not how you chain conditionals

Comment: Yeah, I screwed up the indenting on stackoverflow.

Comment: `if diff != 'average' or 'advanced':` => `if diff not in ('average',  'advanced'):` But you can just use a third `else:` case after your `elif` to make this the same.

Comment: Thanks! But how would that make a difference compared to the original if statement? I understand that both things are different, but I just don't understand how they're different, if that makes sense.

Comment: `diff != 'average' or 'advanced'` parses as `(diff != 'average') or 'advanced'`. The first part, `diff != 'average'`, is a reasonable condition; the second part, `'advanced'`, is always true (it's not a comparison).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap it all into the while loop, I'm new to python but spawning recursive instances of a function seems dangerous to me.

```
def choices():
    global diff
    while true:
        diff = input("Choose a difficulty: Average/Advanced ")
        diff = diff.lower()

        if diff == 'average':
            print('Difficulty set to average.')
            return
        if diff == 'advanced':
            print('Difficulty set to advanced.')
            return
        print('Your input is invalid. Please try again.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first bug lies in this statement:

```
while x > 1:
```

You'll never execute the code within that loop because you set x = 0 at the top of the function.  When it hits the while loop, x = 0 and so the while loop will be completely skipped.

There are a number of other problems, but this one is what's stopping the "if" logic from running.

I'm so confused about this function that I can't determine exactly what you're trying to do so I can't supply a complete working solution to your problem, only the first rather large bug in it.